# How to work with packages in Liquibase

Tags: oracle, view, package, liquibase

We use liquibase with oracle. So we have some packages with procedures inside.
In our case changelog structure looks like:

```
master.xml
|
| release1
|   |
|   release-maser.xml
| release2
|   |
|   release-maser.xml
| softObjects
|   |
|   package-master.xml
|   packages
|      |
|      somePackage.pkb
|      somePackage.pks
```

change sets inside "releases" with runOnChange=false and "softObjects"(that can be create used CREATE OR REPLACE) with runOnChange=true like in best practices:

> Try to maintain separate changelog for Stored Procedures and use
>   runOnChange=”true”. This flag forces LiquiBase to check if the
>   changeset was modified. If so, liquibase executes the change again.

So every update intall some "delta" change sets from "release" and AFTER reinstal all "softObjects" that was changed and in usual case all is OK.

But if I need to setup new DB, I will get a problem:
in change set from second release I use somePackage(v1), but in next release i need to change logic/API somePackage so I will get somePackage(v2) that can not be used in previously created change sets. So for now I have change set that on update will try to use wrong package version.

For avoid this I can add soft objects directly inside release folder without runOnChange=true when i create it. When I need to change it, i should just copy previous version of file to my new release and make changes inside a COPY.

This approach has some disadvantages:

- you make a lot of copy files that can consist from thousands lines of
  code(yes I know that it isn`t good)
- version control system recognize it as a new file (good challenge for
  reviewers)

What i undestand wrong? How should I work with "softObjects", if this objects might be changed?